# how to get sortable id for non sortable class in jquery ui sortable

Tags: jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have 5 Items in an `li` element with an `id`. I want to sort all of the `li` elements except the 3rd. But on submit I want all of the `li` element `id`s in any order, excluding the 3rd one, which will remain in the same position.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="sortable">
    <li id="1">Item 1</li>
    <li id="2">Item 2</li>
    <li id="3" class="unsortable">Item 3</li>
    <li id="4">Item 4</li>
    <li id="5">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
  items: "li:not(.unsortable)",
  stop: function(ev, ui) {
    order = $('.ui-sortable').sortable('toArray').toString();
    console.log(order)
  }
});
$(".sortable").disableSelection();
```

In the console, all of the values are appearing, except for the non sortable class.

```
1,2,4,5
```

I want the results to include "3" e.g.: `1,2,3,4,5`. How can I achieve this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `refreshPositions` method to ensure that all of the items are included in the result you're printing to the console.

The call to `refreshPositions` returns the parent `ul` and from there you can query the `children()` to determine the order. The children will consist of all of the `li` elements, regardless of their "sortability".

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
  items: "li:not(.unsortable)",
  stop: function(ev, ui) {
    //Use map to obtain the ids
    var order = $.map($('.sortable').sortable('refreshPositions').children(), function(item) {
      return item.id;
    }).toString();

    console.log(order)
  }
});
$(".sortable").disableSelection();
```

Click on the below for a quick demo:

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/pgyhtd3o/)**

---

`refreshPositions` [**info**](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refreshPositions)